# Name of the organization in The Cabin in the Woods?

Tags: the-cabin-in-the-woods

In *The Cabin in the Woods* there is some kind of secret organization which makes ritual sacrifices

> to please some gods underneath

Does that organization have some name? I don't remember any name in the film, but maybe the script or the novelization has more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No specific name is mentioned in the film, the script or the official novelisation. The place where Sitterson and the others work is generally referred to as "the facility" (note the small "f") but beyond that, there's nothing.

---

Out of universe, Whedon referred to the controllers as being part of a shadowy organisation, which is where the writers of the unofficial wiki appear to have gotten the idea that the overarching group is called "[The Organization](http://thecabininthewoods.wikia.com/wiki/The_Organization)".

> **Q.** *I’d love to ask you about the story, because I’m interested and
> there’s no source material I can turn to for explanation. **Who is
> coordinating this game between nations?***
>
> **Whedon:** *You know, we keep enough of it secret and shadowy so that we can say
> it’s “a secret, shadowy organization.” Because that’s what you want.
> It’s not that interesting to find out who is elected co-chairman of
> the treasury of **the secret organization.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Joss Whedon Finally Talks Cabin In The Woods Spoilers](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Joss-Whedon-Finally-Talks-Cabin-Woods-Spoilers-30503.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Since the film is a parody of horror movies, I guess it makes sense to avoid specific names.